# How to get values from <li> elements?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have three different sections for filter and a button and i want to use filter on these sections, I just want to know that
how can i get value of these sections ( inside ul li)

```
<div id="new-items" class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="btn-selector nolink">New Items</a>
<ul class="">
  <li><span>New bestsellers</span></li>
  <li><span>New releases</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="buy" class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="btn-selector nolink">Buy Now</a>
  <ul class="">
    <li><span>Wallet</span></li>
    <li><span>Website</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="sort-by" class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="btn-selector nolink">Sort By</a>
  <ul class="">
    <li><span>Low To High Price</span></li>
    <li><span>High To Low Price</span></li>
    <li><span>View</span></li>
    <li><span>View</span></li>
    <li><span>Rating</span></li>
    <li><span>Sale</span></li>
    <li><span>Date</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button class="sc-button style letter style-2 filter"><span>Filter</span> </button>
```

Comment: That's some HTML. You're asking a question about jQuery (and apparently PHP). Provide an example of what you'd like to produce.

Comment: @Chase i want to get selected ( if user selected any field) value in jquery , Hope you understand my point

Comment: what is there for the user to select? What do you mean by `selected`?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius let me try to explain, as you can see in my html code there is three dropdown( ul li) and a "filter" button so whenever use select any dropdown and then click on "filter" button then i want to get value of "clicked items " (all three section value )

Comment: But you're not (currently) recording which items are being clicked?  How are you showing the "drop down"?

Answer (score 1):

This is how your HTML now renders

[image]

You need to convert the `<li>` to radio buttons.
For example, the sort choices.

```
<input type="radio" name="sort" value="1"> Low To High Price<br>
<input type="radio" name="sort" value="2"> High To Low Price<br>
<input type="radio" name="sort" value="3"> View<br>
<input type="radio" name="sort" value="4"> View<br>
<input type="radio" name="sort" value="5"> Rating<br>
<input type="radio" name="sort" value="6"> Sale<br>
<input type="radio" name="sort" value="7"> Date<br>
```

The above looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may not be jQuery but it is simple enough in vanilla Javascript. The comments tell you what is happening.

```js
// a global variable to be populated when specific SPAN elements are clicked.
let selection=false;

// bind a delegated listener to the document or suitable ancestor
document.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  // If the "click" is on a SPAN of interest, populate the global variable
  if( e.target.tagName=='SPAN' && e.target.parentNode.tagName=='LI' ){
    selection=e.target;
  }
  // if the button is clicked, filter ...
  if( e.target.tagName=='SPAN' && e.target.parentNode.tagName=='BUTTON' && selection ){
    alert(selection.textContent)
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="new-items" class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="btn-selector nolink">New Items</a>
  <ul class="">
    <li><span>New bestsellers</span></li>
    <li><span>New releases</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="buy" class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="btn-selector nolink">Buy Now</a>
  <ul class="">
    <li><span>Wallet</span></li>
    <li><span>Website</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="sort-by" class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="btn-selector nolink">Sort By</a>
  <ul class="">
    <li><span>Low To High Price</span></li>
    <li><span>High To Low Price</span></li>
    <li><span>View</span></li>
    <li><span>View</span></li>
    <li><span>Rating</span></li>
    <li><span>Sale</span></li>
    <li><span>Date</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button class="sc-button style letter style-2 filter"><span>Filter</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

get all the li elements inside div, then loop the array

example for the first div:

```
const newItems = document.querySelectorAll('#new-items li');
newItems.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item.innerText);
})
```